# Why Must A Matrix be Symmetric for Orthogonal Diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, orthogonality, orthonormal

So far, all we are doing in class is determine if the matrix **A** is symmetric, find the basis for the eigenspace **P**, and apply Gram Schmidt for it to be orthogonal. My question is; why must **A** be symmetric in the first place?

In the end of the day, we will still apply Gram Schmidt to solve for orthogonal matrices - wont that mean that the inverse of P is the transpose? Does that imply A wont produce a diagonal matrix if it wasn't symmetric? Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not think that any matrix can be diagonalized. The fact that a *symmetric* matrix $A$ can be diagonalized, with an *orthogonal* diagonalizing matrix $P$ (i.e., $P^{-1}=P^T$), is the content of the so-called "Spectral Theorem" for symmetric matrices.

If you allow $A$ to be non-symmetric then you may find out that $A$ does not admit orthogonal diagonalizing matrices, or even that it cannot be diagonalized altogether.